# Illegal characters in path

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmd, nuget

I run the following command in Visual Studio 2012 Tools Command Line:

```
"C:\source\Branch-1\.nuget\nuget.exe" install "C:\source\Branch-1\ClassLibs\WCF\ServiceHosts\PINPoller\packages.config" -source ""  -RequireConsent -solutionDir "C:\source\Branch-1\"
```

I got the error:

```
     Illegal characters in path.
```

This is the error raised when building the solution. I manually copied it to the cmd.

**UPDATED:**

The folder name is there:

> C:\source\Branch-1.nuget
>   [image]

When I just run the portion command,

```
"C:\source\Branch-1\.nuget\nuget.exe" install "C:\source\Branch-1\ClassLibs\WCF\ServiceHosts\PINPoller\packages.config" -source ""
```

It is okay.

Comment: This should NOT have been closed. It has to do with installing code dependencies/libraries and will generally only apply to developers.

Comment: In case anyone else encounters this problem, the real answer is fairly simple -- the trailing slash in your Path value is escaping the closing quote. You can either remove the trailing backslash or add a space before the closing quote marks: `"C:\source\Branch-1\"` should be modified to be either `"C:\source\Branch-1"` or `"C:\source\Branch-1\ "`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably it is the answer at
 http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/398910#post925903

replacing

```
-solutionDir "$(SolutionDir) "
```

with

```
-OutputDirectory "$(SolutionDir)packages\\"
```

in NuGet.targets

Comment: Archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20141015102008/https://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/398910